# iOS Obj-C toggle secure text entry for multiple text fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Newbie in Obj-C here. I have 6 text fields that consist of user's PIN Number

How can I toggle the secure text entry of these 6 UI textFields? There is Button to reveal and unreveal the PIN Number. By default the secure text entry is checked on Storyboard.

After googled a while, I found out this code that is intended to find all text fields inside my view

```
- (NSArray*) findAllTextFieldsInView:(UIView*)view {
    NSMutableArray* textfieldarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id x in [view subviews]) {
        if ([x isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            [textfieldarray addObject:x];

        if ([x respondsToSelector:@selector(subviews)]) {
            [textfieldarray addObjectsFromArray:[self findAllTextFieldsInView:x]];
        }
    }
    return textfieldarray;
}
```

and this is my code

```
- (IBAction) revealPIN:(id)sender {

    if (self.reveal == TRUE) {
        self.reveal = FALSE;
    }
    else {
        self.reveal = TRUE;
    }

    NSArray* allTextFields = [self findAllTextFieldsInView:[self view]];
}
```

I don't know where to put the `textField.secureTextEntry = YES` or `NO`;

I put the boolean so that I can check the toggle status. What I have to do after this? Or is there other more elegant way on how to achieve it? I am confused on how to do this one

Thanks!

Comment: Are all of your textFields added though StoryBoard?

Comment: Have you used storyboard or xib?

Comment: I am using storyboard to design the text fields. I also already put the tag 1 - 6 for each of the textfield. At first I check the secure text entry, then i want the user able to toggle it

Comment: when u r loading the view u need to set all text field 'textField.secureTextEntry = YES'. and  if user click on the **revelAction** ,textField.secureTextEntry = NO. no need bool value

Comment: how many **revelActions** u have ... means each test field as its own **revelActon** or for all textfield u created one **revelAction**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try like this:

```
- (IBAction) revealPIN:(id)sender {

    if (self.reveal == TRUE) {
        self.reveal = FALSE;
    }
    else {
        self.reveal = TRUE;
    }

    NSArray* allTextFields = [self findAllTextFieldsInView:[self view]];

    for tf in allTextFields
    {
       tf.secureTextEntry = self.reveal; // <--- Check this one
    }
}
```

You can also optimize to instead of either finding the textfields first then update their secureTextEntry property, you should create a method that update the text field's property directly like this:

```
- (void) updateSecureEntryAttrForAllTextFieldsInView:(UIView*)view {
    NSMutableArray* textfieldarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id x in [view subviews]) {
        if ([x isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            x.secureTextEntry = self.reveal;  // <--- Check this one

        if ([x respondsToSelector:@selector(subviews)]) {
            [textfieldarray addObjectsFromArray:[self updateSecureEntryAttrForAllTextFieldsInView:x]];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is what I am searching for! Sir you are my day saver!

Answer (score 1):

If you textFiled added through storyboard or xib then you can find this option in interface builder. Select your textfield in storyboard. Here I have attached reference image.

[image]

Please check mark **Secure** option for all of your textfields.

When user tap on "Reveal" change textfield secure option at below place in your code.

```
-(NSArray*)findAllTextFieldsInView:(UIView*)view{
NSMutableArray* textfieldarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(id x in [view subviews]){
    if([x isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
x. secureTextEntry = YES;
        [textfieldarray addObject:x];
}
    if([x respondsToSelector:@selector(subviews)]){
        [textfieldarray addObjectsFromArray:[self findAllTextFieldsInView:x]];
    }
}
return textfieldarray;
}
```

Comment: Sir, I want the user able to toggle the secure text entry. there is button "Reveal" to reveal the PIN number

Comment: Select this option for all textfileds.

Then when user tap on "Reveal" change set textFiled.secure = NO for  that particular textfiled .

Comment: that is what i am trying to achieve. That is why I am asking here Sir, how can I get all the textfields and then toggle the secure text entry

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable the user to show/hide secure entry, you got to use this code in your toggle method:

```
yourTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
yourTextField.secureTextEntry = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using storyboard, I would do the following:

1. In storyboard, you must have a scene (a view controller) whose view contains the 6 text fields as subviews.
2. Ensure that the class of the view controller is set to the name of your `UIViewController` subclass by going to the Identity Inspector. Say your class is called MyViewController.
3. Since you're using Objective-C, go to `MyViewController.m`  Since you need an outlet to each of your text fields, that are all the same type, it's best to use an `IBOutletCollection`.  So add the following class extension to `MyViewController.m`:

   ```
   @interface MyViewController()
   @property (nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UITextFIeld) NSArray *textFields;
   @end
   ```
4. Add each outlet to the collection by using the assistant editor, putting the storyboard on the left of your screen and `MyViewController.m` on the right.  Control drag from each `UITextField` in storyboard to the `textFields` property in `MyViewController.m`.
5. Add the following method to the implementation of `MyViewController.m`:

   ```
   @implementation MyViewController
   - (void)updateTextFieldsWithSecureEntry:(BOOL)secureEntryEnabled {
       for (UITextField *textField in self.textFields) { 
           textField.secureTextEntry = secureEntryEnabled
       }
   }
   @end
   ```
6. You can simply call `[self updateTextFieldsWithSecureEntry: false]` to turn secure entry off on all 6 text fields.